# symfony link_to popup in IE

Tags: php, symfony1, popup, window

Popup window is working fine in firefox and google chrome, but not working in IE8.

Am using:

```
<?php
print link_to(__($user->getTitle()),"/user/jobseeker?jid= ".$user->getJid() , array('popup' => array('Window title', 'width=810,height=600,left=520,top=0')));
?>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: please edit the title of your question to be less generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the issue, but you have a space in the URL string:

```
"/user/jobseeker?jid= ".$user->getJid()
                     ^
```